# MSI - don't require applications to close

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windows-installer

How can I modify my MSI so it doesn't require ALL other running applications to close? Funny enough, if my application is closed manually before the uninstall is closed, it will not ask to close outlook, firefox etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prompt is shown automatically by InstallValidate action, so you cannot modify the behavior. Instead you can prevent it by using a custom action which closes your application before InstallValidate.

Usually this is done by sending WM_CLOSE to the main application window (the application should handle this message for this to work).

The other applications (Outlook, Firefox etc.) are also shown in the prompt because Windows Installer is not very good at detecting running applications. It basically checks file dependencies (for example if multiple applications use the same DLLs or runtime), so false positives may occur.

Comment: I have a custom action for that, under "Uninstall", but it runs AFTER the prompt with running applications... How/where should I put it?

Comment: You should move it before InstallValidate, for example after CostFinalize. Make sure it still uses the REMOVE="ALL" condition to run only during uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

MSI will automatically handle locked files using a reboot scenario.  Asking to close applications is an attempt to prevent that reboot. You can suppress the reboot but then the file won't actually be replaced until after the reboot.

What exactly is the behavior you are looking for?

BTW, recommended reading:

[FilesInUse Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

From there follow the link to InstallValidate and System Reboots.

Comment: I want the setup to either ignore running applications automatically, or end my application before evaluating running applications - tried doing that with custom actions, see comment to @Cosmin

Comment: I tried putting my customaction into installexecutesequnce under number 50 (before everything), but it is not executed. It has a condition =2, that should be right?

Comment: What do you want to happen when ignoring?

Answer (score 1):

As mrnx wrote here this check for running applications happens during **InstallValidate**.
But stopping applications before it is not a good idea. Other checks might fail and MSI must be able to recover the system to the state it was before running MSI, including running applications.

Plus these checks run as "immediate", not "deferred".

IMO Custom Actions to stop applications should run just before "**RemoveFiles**" and as "**deferred**" to make sure it runs as admin.

Now to prevent dialog from showing the following property can be used:

> ```
> <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />
> ```

In my understanding it will still fall back to **FilesInUse** dialog during **RemoveFiles** should they still be used at that time.